# Make Data columns from a sql adapter

Tags: c#, sql

Is there a way, where I can use a sql adapter and convert the sql query results into a Data Columns? I'm kinda new a datatables. I need to build this dynamically since my column names are stored into a sql table. I keep running into datarows not columns. What I have built so far:

```
string feedcolumns = @"select FeedColumnName from  myTable where FeedProcessID = @feedprocessid";

SqlCommand columnscommand = new SqlCommand(feedcolumns, connUpd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("datafeed");

foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    dc = new 
    dt.Columns.Add(dc);
}
```

Comment: The method you are looking for is `DataAdapter.Fill(dt)`. The `Columns` collection of the `DataTable` will be filled dynamically from the resultset of the query. There is no need to do that on your own. These columns apply to all rows in the table, and their column indexes correspond to the field index in each row. You can also address each field in a row by its column name: `dr.Rows[rowindex]["columnname"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can fill a DataTable directly from an SqlReader, no need to go column by column.
One thing I did notice was that your SQL statement had a parameter in it that was never assigned to the command object, so I added it in

```
string feedcolumns = "select FeedColumnName from  myTable where FeedProcessID = @feedprocessid";

DataTable dt = new DataTable("datafeed");

using (SqlConnection connUpd = new SqlConnection("MyConnection")) {
    using (SqlCommand columnscommand = new SqlCommand(feedcolumns, connUpd)) {
        columnscommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@feedprocessid", feedprocessid);

        connUpd.Open();

        var dataReader = columnscommand.ExecuteReader();

        dt.Load(dataReader);
    }
}
```